# Conversion problem of projection of MODIS LAI from sinusoidal to geographic

Tags: coordinate-system, erdas-imagine, modis, envi, lai

I am trying to change MODIS data's (LAI) sinusoidal projection to geographic. Actually I did it. But when I reproject it by ERDAS, the output LAI raster moved about 10 km to west side of actual shapefile and I tried it by ENVI, the output raster also moved about 20 km but to north side of shapefile. I am using the shapefile to check accuracy of the output raster. It was shape of lake.

Also I have tried it in R to convert projection using following script

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
Sys.setenv(TZ='GMT')

lai_real <-raster("E:\\LAI\\LAI_hdf\\MOD15A2_LAI_2014\\New Folder\\mod15a2.a2014169.h23_26.img")    
projection(lai_real) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")      
writeRaster(lai_real, filename="E:\\LAI\\LAI_hdf\\MOD15A2_LAI_2014\\New Folder\\mod15a2.a2014169.h23_26_geo.img", datatype='FLT8S', overwrite=TRUE)
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I convert the projection of the LAI from sinusoidal to geographic (lat/long)?

If my explanation is unclear, please visit the link that shared below. I hope then you understand what problem I have to convert sinusoidal to Geographic (WGS84)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cucntnt8kh7m1dl/Hovsgol.PNG.

Comment: projection()<- assigns a crs, it does not do the transformation. Do you really need to warp this yhing or do you just want to extract from it?

Comment: Please visit the link that I shared below. Then you can clearly understand what problem I have. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cucntnt8kh7m1dl/Hovsgol.PNG

Comment: I understand, I just think you have a job to do but this is a distraction. If this is the job, confirm the source crs is right and then use projectRaster to transform to the target crs. What is projection(lai_real) directly after you load it with raster?